# Accessing ws-secured soap webs service using groovy wslite

Tags: soap, groovy

Has any one used groovy ws-lite to access user name token secured SOAP web service?

The documentation states that only basic authentication can be used. is there a way we can send out user name token in HTTP header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can use wslite to acess WS-secured web services. We should use markubuilder to create the WSE security header element.

The following post gave me the idea and I was able to access the SOAP service by building the Security element.

http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td5679705